# PHP: $mysqli not found

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm probably doing something really stupid but here's the deal.
I've created a class named Database, it's very simple and hold only 2 functions. Just for opening and closing the mysqli connection.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("sdl_config.php");

class Database {
/* Open the connection with the database */
    public function OpenConnection() {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        if($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connection Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
        } else {
            echo 'Connection Succeeded';
        }
    }

/* Close the connection with the database */
    public function CloseConnection() { 
        if($mysqli) {
            $mysqli->close();
            echo 'Connection Closed';
        } else {
            echo 'Connection does not exist';
        }
    }
}
```

To test this I've created another page just calling the 2 functions.

```
<?php
require_once("include/class.database.php");

Database::OpenConnection();
Database::CloseConnection();
```

Opening the connection works perfectly but the issue then comes at the CloseConnection function. It will never find the $mysqli variable, how is this possible when I've opened it the line before?

ALso, I've read that some people say that closing the connection manually is kinda obsolete and others say it's best to do so. So what's the best practice here and WHEN should the connection be closed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is because `$mysqli` in the second function is out of scope from the first function. You would have to pass the resource into the second function in order for the second function to work properly.

Comment: Why dont you try to make `$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);` a private variable in the top of the class?

Comment: Oh man.... Read up pn PHP OOP. First declare `protected $mysqli;` and then use `$this->mysqli` to access/modify the DB handle. Oh, and you can't call those methods statically...

Comment: create your connection property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables defined within functions are local and visible only within that function itself.

You should use what OOP allows us to do and make that variable a class' property:

```
class Database {
    private $mysqli;
/* Open the connection with the database */
    public function OpenConnection() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        if($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connection Error (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->mysqli->connect_error );
        } else {
            echo 'Connection Succeeded';
        }
    }

/* Close the connection with the database */
    public function CloseConnection() { 
        if($this->mysqli) {
            $this->mysqli->close();
            echo 'Connection Closed';
        } else {
            echo 'Connection does not exist';
        }
    }
}
```

But you need now to use object of a class:

```
<?php
require_once("include/class.database.php");

$db = new Database;
$db->OpenConnection();
$db->CloseConnection();
```

**Reference:**

- [Manual on variables' scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
- [Manual on classes](http://php.net/manual/en/classobj.examples.php)

Comment: Thank you for this insight. Do you also have some comments on when to use mysqli->close ? :)